# Apache & Core Usage

Tags: apache-2.2, cpu-usage

If you have like... 10 cores... and you use Apache and your load average is always under 5.0...

Would it slow your site any if you lowered to 6 cores?

(assuming you never reached any spikes that hit 6.0 in load)

Specs:
Xen, 10 Cores at 2.0GHz, CentOS 5 64bit, using "uptime" to find load averages.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe.

The problem is that the load average is exactly that -- an *average*.  Sure, over the course of a minute you never got above 5 processes in the run queue, but what about in a particular second or so?  You might have big spikes and just never know it.  If you don't care about small latency spikes, you might get away with it.

Comment: @dav this is the main point - a 1-minute load average of 5 might be a constant, continuous load of five threads saturating five cores, but it might also be 10 threads saturating 10 cores for half a minute and idling for the other half. In the latter case, halving the number of cores would increase response times for your users by the factor of 2.